# RedBean PHP не работает R::store

Tags: php, update

```
    <?php
      require "../db.php";
      $date = $_POST;

      if(isset($_POST['do_signup'])) {
        $data = R::load('data', 'id=0');
        $data->ref = $date['ref'];
        $data->lec = $date['lec'];
        $data->shor = $date['shpor'];
        $data->text = $date['text'];
        R::store($data);
        header('Location: index.php');
       }

    ?>
```

В базе еще есть поля id, number.

Все данные правильные, не знаю почему не работает. 
P.S Новичок в RedBean

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вы создаете новую запись или изменяете существующую?

Answer (score 1):

```
$data= R::dispense('data'); 

$data->ref = $date['ref']; 

$data->lec = $date['lec']; 

$id = R::store($letter);
```